# How do Torbutton and Tor change IP?

Tags: firefox, ip

1. I was wondering how Torbutton and
   Tor change IP when browsing internet
   using Firefox?
2. I learned that using proxy can
   change IP to be the IP of the proxy
   server. But is the way by Torbutton
   and Tor the same as using a proxy?
3. With Torbutton and Tor, why is IP only changed when browsing
   internet using Firefox, and not
   changed outside Firefox, such as
   using a different browser
   application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering how Torbutton and Tor change IP when browsing internet using Firefox?

Torbutton does not change anything. It just tells Firefox to use Tor.

When you use a proxy server, the browser sends all your HTTP requests to that server, which forwards them to their final destination.

- browser ↔ proxy server ↔ web server

Your actual address is not changed, it's only disguised, because the web server only sees what connected to it *directly* – in this case, the proxy.

(However, if someone takes control over the proxy, they can monitor everything sent through it (such as who uploaded files to Site X). Often, it's the server's owner themselves.)

With Tor, the request is routed through several servers, and encrypted separately for each:

- browser ↔ Tor on your computer
- Tor on your computer [[[↔]]] node A [[↔]] node B [↔] node C ↔ web server

  (Each [ ] represents a layer of encryption.)

This way, the web server only sees a connection coming from node C, while C only sees a connection from B. Only node A knows where the user is, but it doesn't know what the user is transferring.

(This is called [onion routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_routing). See also [Tor Overview](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en).)

---

> I learned that using proxy can change IP to be the IP of the proxy server. But is the way by Torbutton and Tor the same as using a proxy?

Tor *is* a proxy, but it works in a different way than the "proxy servers" you're used to. See description above.

Torbutton, again, is only a button that reconfigures Firefox.

---

> With Torbutton and Tor, why is IP only changed when browsing internet using Firefox, and not changed outside Firefox, such as using a different browser application?

Torbutton is a *Firefox* add-on and is only able to reconfigure *Firefox*. Tor does not change any settings itself – when you start it, it only waits for connections. You yourself have to tell programs to connect through it.

If the program supports using a SOCKS 5 proxy server, point it to `127.0.0.1:9050`. If it only supports HTTP proxies, you'll need Polipo, which comes with the Tor Bundle, and runs at `127.0.0.1:8123`.

Comment: I've been using tor for years and couldn't have summarized it that well.

Comment: @grawity: Thanks! I observe that the ip selected by Tor changes constantly, and I am not aware that my internet connection disconnect and reconnect. So does it mean Tor changes ip automatically for the same internet connect session?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, when you connect through Tor, it builds new circuits every so often, to avoid being tracked. (If you installed the Tor/Vidalia bundle, you can see this in Vidalia's "Network Map".) By the way, this has got absolutely nothing with your "real" Internet connection. Tor doesn't touch it in any way.

Comment: ...by which I mean Tor doesn't **change** it in any way, only uses it like any other program would.

Comment: @grawity: Thanks! (1) Will constantly changing ip make the fact of hiding ip obvious? Is it possible to fix an ip?  (2) How does Tor find so many proxies, while it is not easy to find them by myself?

Comment: @Tim: 1) No, for two reasons: 1. the same circuit is re-used for all successive connections to the same location, 2. when a new address is chosen, the site will simply think you are a different user. 2) It doesn't use the same old proxies as you find on Google; it connects to the Tor network specifically. Someone who has a fast connection can simply install Tor and change one setting to join the network. Many contribute 24/7 servers, others run Tor on their home connection, and all of them are used.

Comment: @grawity: Thanks! If downloading files from some fileshare websites, will Tor changing IP interrupt the downloading?

Comment: @Tim: However, two points you should note. One, the Tor network keeps a list of all its nodes, so a website can simply look up your new address on the list, and it will know that you are using Tor. (It *won't* know who you are or where you are from, just that you are connecting through Tor.) Two, anonymous proxies are abused more often than you can ever imagine. Because of this, people rarely ever publicize their proxy servers, or if they do, they in fact keep detailed logs to avoid legal trouble. With Tor, it's different: the server operator doesn't and cannot know who connected to what.

Comment: @Tim: The address doesn't change "constantly". When a connection is established, Tor never moves it to a different exit node, so you have the same address for the entire duration of that connection. (Other connections at the same time may get different paths.)

Comment: @Tim: But please remember what I said earlier - the network is run by volunteers. People using Tor to download huge amounts of data from BitTorrent or YouTube are seriously harming the network.

Comment: @Tim: The address doesn't change "constantly" -- it couldn't even work that way. A basic TCP connection is tied to the two addresses that established it. Therefore, when you make a connection through Tor, it makes sure that you keep the same address for the entire duration of that connection. (Other connections at the same time may get different circuits, though.)

Comment: @grawity: Thanks! I will be careful about the downloading thing. My last comment was about downloading some file, for example,  from rapidshare.com, which requires a consistent IP during the downloading period. If Tor changes proxy in the middle of downloading, I was wondering if that will interrupt such downloading?

Comment: @Tim: If the address changed, yes, it would break, because as I said, a TCP connection is tied to the initial addresses. It's not even specific to RapidShare, it's how the Internet works. And as I also said, Tor *knows that*, and it will not change servers for an existing connection: the "node C ↔ web server" part will not change. **However,** if you close that connection and open a new one, there *is* a chance that it will go through a different address. But Tor *attempts* to reuse the same circuit for all successive connections to the same destination (e.g. RapidShare)..

Answer (score 1):

1.)You're really asking how oinion routing works which is incredibly complex and beyond the scope of this site. Here's a good summary.

http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/what-is-tor-project-and-how-tor-works-complete-guide/

2.) It's not the same as a proxy although it does use proxy services

3.) tor doesn't proxify everything by default. You need to set up each app to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor site actually has a pretty good description of how onion routing works. Essentially each Tor node encapsulates the requests that it receives and forwards the encapsulated request to the next node.

The ability of Tor to hide originating source addresses from the destination server is dependant on the traffic that is being passed. In general, the destination server will see the IP address of the last hop Tor node; however this is not always the case. For example, a website might embed some Javascript that submits the local IP address into some form data.

Only the applications that are configured to use Tor a proxy will benefit.